# pygame does not access sprite functions after putting the dot "."

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I am following a tutorial for a game of ships, and when creating the Player class in the **init** function I have a strange problem when wanting to access the functions of the Sprite module: when I write the name of the variable and put the point to access its functions remain in white, instead of being colored yellow indicating that it is a reserved word (I am using visual studio)

(Sorry if I do not express myself correctly I am using google translator.)

so the strange is this:
[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wgz7.png)

what is indicated in the red boxes should be in yellow (like what I underlined in yellow), since theoretically it would be accessing the functions of a Sprite object therefore it should be highlighted in yellow ...
the problem is that it appears white, as if it did not recognize the variable as a Sprite object

Here is where i create the image directory.

```
import pygame, random, os, sys
from os import path

img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'img')
```

And here is the Meteor class:

```
class Meteor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.image_orig = random.choice(meteor_images)
    self.image_orig.set_colorkey("black")
    self.image_orig.set_clip()
    self.image = self.image_orig.copy()
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.radius = int(self.rect.width*0.85/2) # *0.85 <- se leeria como (el 85% del width) / 2
    pygame.draw.circle(self.image, "red", self.rect.center, self.radius)
    self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, width)
    self.rect.bottom = random.randrange(-100, -50)
    self.speedx = random.randrange(-4, 4)
    self.speedy = random.randrange(2, 8)
    self.rot = 0
    self.rot_speed = random.randrange(-8, 8)
    self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

and then here is where create the meteors list:

```
meteor_images = []
meteor_list = ['meteorBrown_big1.png',
               'meteorBrown_big2.png',
               'meteorBrown_big3.png',
               'meteorBrown_big4.png']
for img in meteor_list:
    meteor_images.append(pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, img)).convert())
```

I am not very expert on the subject, what could be the problem??